# Can we specify the pumping length while applying pumping lemma

Tags: pumping-lemma

In all the examples I have seen, the pumping length $p$ is not specified. The string is a pattern that somehow has the $p$. E.g. when proving $L=\{a^n b^n c^n | n \geq 0\}$ is not context free, we assume the string $s \in L$ has the form $a^pb^pc^p$, and continue.

Do we have to select such a general pattern?

E.g. Can I just say, $s=aaabbbccc$, where $p=3$, and reason continuing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pumping lemma states that if $L$ is regular, then $\exists p.\forall w.\exists x,y,z. w=xyz \wedge$ they can be "pumped"

Thus to show that $L$ is **not** regular, we must show $\neg(\exists p.\forall w.\exists x,y,z. w=xyz \wedge$ they can be "pumped"$)$
which is equivalent to $\forall p. \exists w. \forall x,y,z.w=xyx\wedge($ all other requirements given in the lemma$)\rightarrow\exists.n$ they cannot be "pumped" n times

This shows us its **nessecary to never assume what p is.**

Furthermore, it explains why we need to find only one word (which depends on p).